# Showing a change in a shelved perforce file

Tags: perforce

If a colleague has a file shelved in perforce, and I'd like to diff the file in the shelved changelist against the source version of that file what is the perforce command needed to do this?

For example if the file a.txt is shelved in changelist 156222 how do I view the changes to a.txt that are in the shelved changelist vs. the current review of a.txt

Answer (score 10):

If you know the revision of the shelved file (e.g. #4) and the head revision (#3 in this case) you can use

```
p4 diff2 //path/to/depot/file#3 //path/to/depot/file@=<changenumber>
```

or - even easier - you can use `p4 describe` (see [manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/describe.html)):

```
p4 describe -S <changenumber>
```

Find the changenumber with:

```
p4 changes -u <user> -s shelved
```

Comment: The diff2 example is incorrect, because #4 does not exist yet as submitted revision. You have to use @= syntax to refer to a shelved revision. E.g.: 

`p4 diff2 //path/to/depot/file#3 //path/to/depot/file@=12345`

(assuming 12345 is the shelved changelist).

Comment: Thanks, will fix in the answer

Answer (score 5):

If you are using P4V, you can go to your Pending tab and select the "User" and "Workspace" of your colleague (with the help of the drop-down "Browse..." option).

Then you will see his/her Pending lists, being it composed of shelved files or not. From there, the normal "Diff Against" will work for the "a.txt" file.

Comment: Yes with p4v it's definitely possible but I want to do this from the command line.

Comment: You didn't mention the command line restriction on the question. You probably know that in P4V you can see the corresponding commands executed for a given task. So, in P4V, if you go on Edit->Preferences->General and check on "Show p4 reporting commands.." and "Show p4 command output.." you can discover all the commands required to execute the steps I described above. Maybe that helps.

Comment: The logging option truncates the p4 command so it's not all there.

Comment: @Lee, check your preferences in `Edit->Preferences` and go to the `General` tab and look under `Log options:` to ensure p4v is logging everything.  For future reference though, you do need to mention that you want to do something from the command line.